# Remove and Add class using jQuery with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im using Jquery to remove and add class to the active tab on my navigation.  However the active class will not remove after a new tab is clicked.  Please see gist for more.  I do not know why the class will not remove when a new tab is clicked or the user scrolls to a new section.

https://gist.github.com/flyspaceage/5720a4aa75815c20d6d703607f9d27c0

```css
.active-break {
  background-color: #6390C6 !important;
}

.active-why {
  background-color: #6E8F82 !important;
}

.active-test {
  background-color: #E77C22 !important;
}

.active-deep {
  background-color: #466EA5 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <!-- <li>
        <a class="nav" href="#intro" class="nav-intro">
         Top
        </a>
       </li> -->
  <li>
    <a id="one" class="nav nav-break" href="#breaking-away">Breaking Away</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="two" class="nav nav-why" href="#why-right-now">Why Right OnCourse</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="three" class="nav nav-test" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="four" class="nav nav-deep" href="#deep-dive">Deep Dive</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="five" class="nav nav-resources" href="#resources">Resources</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
/*
 * Scrollify
 **/
$(function(){
    $.scrollify({
        section: ".scrollify-section",
        interstitialSection : ".leaf .contact .footer",
        setHeights: false,
        touchScroll: false,

        before:function(i,panels) {
          var ref = panels[i].attr("data-section-name");

          $(".pagination .active").removeClass("active");

          $(".pagination").find("a[href=\"#" + ref + "\"]").addClass("active");

          var ref = panels[i].attr("data-section-name");

          if(ref==="breaking-away") {
            $(".breaking-away .carousel-box-shadow").addClass("animate");
          }
          if(ref==="intro") {
            $(".breaking-away .carousel-box-shadow").removeClass("animate");
          }
          if(ref==="testimonials") {
            $(".breaking-away .carousel-box-shadow").removeClass("animate");
          }
        },

        afterRender:function() {
          var pagination = "<ul class=\"pagination\">";
          var activeClass = "";
          $(".panel").each(function(i) {
            activeClass = "";
            if(i===0) {
              activeClass = "active";
            }
            pagination += "<li><a class=\"" + activeClass + "\" href=\"#" + $(this).attr("data-section-name") + "\"><span class=\"hover-text\">" + $(this).attr("data-section-name").charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $(this).attr("data-section-name").slice(1) + "</span></a></li>";
          });

          pagination += "</ul>";

        }
    });
});
```

/*** Color active tab ***/

```
var selectorOne = '#one';

$(selectorOne).on('click', function(){
    $(selectorOne).removeClass('active-break');
    $(this).addClass('active-break');
});

var selectorTwo = '#two';

$(selectorTwo).on('click', function(){
    $(selectorTwo).removeClass('active-why');
    $(this).addClass('active-why');
});

var selectorThree = '#three';

$(selectorThree).on('click', function(){
    $(selectorThree).removeClass('active-test');
    $(this).addClass('active-test');
});

var selectorFour = '#four';

$(selectorFour).on('click', function(){
    $(selectorFour).removeClass('active-deep');
    $(this).addClass('active-deep');
});
```

Comment: that link you posted is just a bunch of code -_-a

Comment: Please include in your question the logic that you are using to move the class around.

Comment: I apologize, I have reposted the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last block of Javascript is the relevant one. You need to clear all the classes from *all* of the items before applying the active class to the one that was clicked. You will need to do that no matter which one was clicked. This solution should work for you:

```
$('#one').on('click', function(){
    $('.pagination a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active-break');
});

$('#two').on('click', function(){
    $('.pagination a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active-why');
});

$('#three').on('click', function(){
    $('.pagination a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active-test');
});

$('#four').on('click', function(){
    $('.pagination a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active-deep');
});
```

Comment: thanks, I was trying to add all of the classes within the removeClass method, but I see i need to put it before and actually use the parent not the class.